# Debezium: Unable to setup watcher on Kafka-Connect Docker container. Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 2 ... LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE

Tags: sql-server, docker, apache-kafka, debezium

**Question:**

How do I setup watcher to watch a Kafka-Connect stream in real-time as changes are made to the database? I am getting `Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 2 : {dbhistory.Test.Posts=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}`. What is causing the problem and how do I fix it?

**Context:**

This question is related to: [Debezium How do I correctly register the SqlServer connector with Kafka Connect - connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61090021/debezium-how-do-i-correctly-register-the-sqlserver-connector-with-kafka-connect/61104392#61104392) and
 https://github.com/debezium/debezium-examples/blob/master/tutorial/README.md#using-sql-server

In Windows 10, I have setup Zookeeper, Kafka, and Kafka-Connector all in their own separate Docker containers using the following commands:

```
docker run -it --rm --name zookeeper -p 2181:2181 -p 2888:2888 -p 3888:3888 debezium/zookeeper:1.1
docker run -it --rm --name kafka -p 9092:9092 -e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka --link zookeeper:zookeeper debezium/kafka:1.1
docker run -it --rm --name connect -p 8083:8083 -e GROUP_ID=1 -e CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_configs -e OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_offsets -e STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_statuses --link zookeeper:zookeeper --link kafka:kafka debezium/connect:1.1
```

I then setup a Kafka Connector to an instance of SQL Server that is running on the localhost, outside of a Docker container. The logs show that the connector can connect to the database and grab the CDC data. Up until this point I am OK.

However, when I try to create a watcher, using the following command:

```
docker run -it --rm --name watcher --link zookeeper:zookeeper --link kafka:kafka debezium/kafka:1.1
```

I get the following error.

```
watch-topic -a -k dbhistory.Test.Posts
WARNING: Using default BROKER_ID=1, which is valid only for non-clustered installations.
Using ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=172.17.0.2:2181
Using KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://172.17.0.5:9092
Using KAFKA_BROKER=172.17.0.3:9092
Contents of topic dbhistory.Test.Posts:
[2020-04-08 15:18:39,373] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-3848-1, groupId=console-consumer-3848] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 2 : {dbhistory.Test.Posts=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-04-08 16:41:20,501] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-3848-1, groupId=console-consumer-3848] Connection to node 1 (/172.17.0.3:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-04-08 16:41:20,605] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-3848-1, groupId=console-consumer-3848] Connection to node 1 (/172.17.0.3:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-04-08 16:41:20,807] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-3848-1, groupId=console-consumer-3848] Connection to node 1 (/172.17.0.3:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-04-08 16:41:21,262] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-3848-1, groupId=console-consumer-3848] Connection to node 1 (/172.17.0.3:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-04-08 16:41:22,120] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-3848-1, groupId=console-consumer-3848] Connection to node 1 (/172.17.0.3:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-04-08 16:41:23,330] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-3848-1, groupId=console-consumer-3848] Connection to node 1 (/172.17.0.3:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-04-08 16:41:24,189] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-3848-1, groupId=console-consumer-3848] Connection to node 1 (/172.17.0.3:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-04-08 16:41:59,826] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-3848-1, groupId=console-consumer-3848] Connection to node 1 (/172.17.0.3:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-04-08 16:42:04,051] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-3848-1, groupId=console-consumer-3848] Connection to node 1 (/172.17.0.3:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-04-08 16:42:07,121] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-3848-1, groupId=console-consumer-3848] Connection to node 1 (/172.17.0.3:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-04-08 16:42:08,024] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-3848-1, groupId=console-consumer-3848] Connection to node 1 (/172.17.0.3:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-04-08 16:42:09,354] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-3848-1, groupId=console-consumer-3848] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 11570 : {dbhistory.Test.Posts=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-04-08 16:42:09,458] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-3848-1, groupId=console-consumer-3848] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 11572 : {dbhistory.Test.Posts=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-04-08 16:42:09,571] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-3848-1, groupId=console-consumer-3848] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 11574 : {dbhistory.Test.Posts=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-04-08 16:42:09,677] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-3848-1, groupId=console-consumer-3848] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 11576 : {dbhistory.Test.Posts=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-04-08 16:42:09,786] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-3848-1, groupId=console-consumer-3848] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 11578 : {dbhistory.Test.Posts=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-04-08 16:42:09,895] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-3848-1, groupId=console-consumer-3848] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 11580 : {dbhistory.Test.Posts=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-04-08 16:42:10,002] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-3848-1, groupId=console-consumer-3848] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 11582 : {dbhistory.Test.Posts=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-04-08 16:42:10,112] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-3848-1, groupId=console-consumer-3848] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 11584 : {dbhistory.Test.Posts=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-04-08 16:42:10,220] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-3848-1, groupId=console-consumer-3848] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 11586 : {dbhistory.Test.Posts=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-04-08 16:42:10,326] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-3848-1, groupId=console-consumer-3848] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 11588 : {dbhistory.Test.Posts=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-04-08 16:42:10,435] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-3848-1, groupId=console-consumer-3848] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 11590 : {dbhistory.Test.Posts=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-04-08 16:42:10,537] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-3848-1, groupId=console-consumer-3848] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 11592 : {dbhistory.Test.Posts=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-04-08 16:42:10,648] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-3848-1, groupId=console-consumer-3848] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 11594 : {dbhistory.Test.Posts=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-04-08 16:42:10,751] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-3848-1, groupId=console-consumer-3848] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 11596 : {dbhistory.Test.Posts=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-04-08 16:42:10,854] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-3848-1, groupId=console-consumer-3848] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 11598 : {dbhistory.Test.Posts=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-04-08 17:08:48,268] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-3848-1, groupId=console-consumer-3848] Connection to node 1 (/172.17.0.3:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-04-08 17:09:55,602] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-3848-1, groupId=console-consumer-3848] Connection to node 1 (/172.17.0.3:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

Comment: Hi,
these two lines are in clear cotradiction
```
Using KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://172.17.0.5:9092
Using KAFKA_BROKER=172.17.0.3:9092
```
The IP should be the same in both cases. What is IP of the KAfka container?
Also is `-e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka` the correct format? I am usually using equal sign when setting env vars

Comment: @JiriPechanec I see that in the error, but how do I fix it? Please note that I am using the default values provided to me on the help site. My assumption is that they should work out of the box.

Comment: Do you have the option of using Docker Compose? It will make your life a *lot* easier. I can provide an answer based on Docker Compose if this would be acceptable.

Comment: Yes. For a Proof of Concept. Right now I am setting it up to run in Docker. The requirement is that Debezium must connect to an instance of SQL Server that is on the machine and not in a Docker Container. Ultimately, it will run outside of Docker.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try once adding --network=host in the docker run.

Comment: I am no longer on this project, so I have not way of testing to confirm if this is the answer. None the less, I have upvoted it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely caused by the way you defined your environment variable.

Replace:

```
-e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka
```

with:

```
-e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=kafka
```

Comment: I am no longer on this project, so I have not way of testing to confirm if this is the answer. None the less, I have upvoted it. Thank you.